# Find bad shortcut files in windows

Tags: windows-search, autocad

I need to be able to find all the shortcut files on a shared network drive and get rid of any bad ones. I would prefer a basic windows search that I can look over manually and choose which ones to delete. I am open to programs if I have to use them but they need to let me choose where to search and show the path the shortcut points to before I get rid of it.

A search that works for server 2k3 or a windows 8.1 pro pc will work.

Backstory: I have been trying to track down the cause of slowdowns for autocad for a while now and I seem to have tracked it to the existence of shortcuts leading to bad paths. The reason I need to look over them rather than automate it is that while most users will have the drive mapped as  F:\ neither my pc (8 Pro mapped as Z:) nor the server itself will be able to follow any shortcuts mapped as f:\ but they should be left if they are valid for everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I need to be able to find all the shortcut files get rid of any bad ones.

Take a look at [lnk-parser](https://code.google.com/p/lnk-parser/)

> LNK Parser allows you to view the content of Windows shortcut (.LNK)
>   files.
>
> **Command-line Usage**
>
> You can run the program from a command-line and supply a shortcut file
>   or a directory.
>
> **If a directory is supplied, the directory and any sub-directories will
>   be scanned for shortcut files**.
>
> Example 1:
>
> `lnk_parser_cmd.exe shortcut.lnk`
>
> Example 2:
>
> `lnk_parser_cmd.exe C:\Users\User\Desktop`
>
> There are additional options that can be specified to allow you to
>   generate various reports of the shortcut file information.
>
> The following is a list of supported options:
>
> - -o Sets the output directory for reports.
> - -w Generates an HTML report.
> - -c Generates a comma-separated values (CSV) report.
> - -r Remnant and unprocessed data will be dumped to the HTML report.
> - -s Prevents the console from outputting information.
>
> Example:
>
> `lnk_parser_cmd.exe -o Output -w -c -r -s shortcut.lnk`
>
> If you wish to save the command-line output to a file, you can use the
>   redirect operator.
>
> Example:
>
> `lnk_parser_cmd.exe shortcut.lnk > output.txt`
>
> You can speed up the extraction and report generation by redirecting
>   the command-line output to the NUL device, or by using the -s option
>   mentioned above.
>
> Example 1:
>
> `lnk_parser_cmd.exe shortcut.lnk > NUL`
>
> Example 2:
>
> `lnk_parser_cmd.exe -s shortcut.lnk`
>
> The program can also be run normally (not through the command-line).
>   It will ask for the shortcut file or directory, and whether you wish
>   to include a report(s).
>
> When specifying a file or directory path, it's best to surround it
>   with quotes since spaces within the path might be interpreted as
>   separate options.

Code license is GNU GPL v3 .

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with lnk-parser in any way.